# Por que o `fullscreenchange` não funciona ao pressionar F11? Como detectar se alterou para fullscreen no navegador?

Tags: javascript

Estava tentando achar alguma forma de detectar se a página entrou no modo de "tela cheia", por exemplo apertado F11.

---

Eu vi que existe um evento [fullscreenchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event), mas ele aparece não funcionar ao apertar F11. Ele só funciona se o próprio JS acionar o fullscreen (usando o [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

---

O código que usei e QUE NÃO FUNCIONA, foi:

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    console.log("fullscreen", e);
});
```

Quando aperto F11 era esperado que mostrasse a mensagem, mas não parece. Só parece se chamar via `document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();`.

EDIT: O `matchMedia` também NÃO funciona:

```
window.matchMedia('(display-mode: fullscreen)').addListener(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})

window.matchMedia('(display-mode: fullscreen)').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

---

**Tem algum outro evento ou forma de saber quando a janela entre (ou sai) do modo de tela-cheia?**

Comment: Você pode utilizar o evento ```keydown``` para detectar a tecla **F11** (*keyCode 122*) só não saberás se entrou em tela cheia ou saiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei porque não dá para usar o `fullscreenchange`, mas tem como fazer uma **gambiarra** usando [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

O `resize` funciona ao ir para o `fullscreen`, mesmo ao clicar o F11. Para saber se está ou não em fullscreen tem como usar o `window.innerHeight` combinado com o `screen.height`. O `screen.height` é o tamanho total, então ele só será igual se estiver em fullscreen.

O `document.fullscreenElement` não funciona também, ao clicar F11, então não tem como confiar ele. Mas, talvez possa utiliza-lo antes de apelar para a gambiarra.

---

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    if (window.document.fullscreenElement !== null || window.innerHeight === screen.height) {
        console.log("é fullscreen");
        return
    }
     
    console.log("não é fullscreen");
})
```